# Проверка подключения PDO

Tags: php

Почему ругается на try?
Если делать без класса, то работает, а в классе не работает

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'try' (T_TRY), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

```
class Db{
    protected $pdo;

    try{
        public function __construct(){
            $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=dz; charset=utf8', 'root', '');
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
$con = new Db();
```

Comment: Вам бы стоило прочитать про основы ООП.

Answer (score 3):

Потому, что `try` не является допустимой конструкцией в этом месте. В теле класса можно только определять свойства и методы. Все. Использовать `try` (в контексте класса) можно только внутри методов.

В вашем случае надо делать так:

```
class Db{
    protected $pdo;

    public function __construct(){
        try{
            $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=dz; charset=utf8', 'root', '');
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
$con = new Db();
```